Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
Error details:

Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Please share your ideas to solve this issue

so I had the same error too. I'll try to explain in my English (I'm an Italian developer...I hope my English is clear). In practice, MvcJsonOptions from version 8.0 onwards of Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) is deprecated. So you need to use its "evolution" which would be System.Text.Json.
I'll give you an example:
We configure the options in Program.cs or Startup.cs as described below:
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; // Example configuration
    });

Remember to remove all references to MvcJsonOptions throughout the project and replace them with the new JSON management technology.
Another alternative you could use is NewtonsoftJson. There are guides on the internet to install NewtonsoftJson.
I hope I have been of help to you.
Let me know please.
Bye.

In my project Program.cs contains following,
Please, where to add your code in my Program.cs,
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => new WebHostBuilder() .UseKestrel() .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment; var sharedFolder = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "..", "Shared"); .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, "SharedSettings.json"), optional: true) config.AddEnvironmentVariables(); }).UseStartup().Build();

Where to add your code in my startup.cs,
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) { Configuration = configuration; } public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { baseConfigureServices(services, "Gold Loans API", "v1"); } public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) { if (env.IsDevelopment()) { app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); } else { app.UseHsts(); } app.UseHttpsRedirection(); baseConfigure(app, env, "API"); }
